# Get multiple Image download URLs from Firebase Storage- I can successfully upload multiple images

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload multiple images to firebase storage at once. I can upload successfully but cannot retrieve the download URLs;

```
Future<void> saveImages() async {
    int index = images.length;
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    try {
      final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child('images/${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid}');
      images.forEach((element) async {
        final file = await element.file;
        final refPut = ref.child('$element$index');
        await refPut.putFile(
          File(file!.path),
        );
      });
      final ref2 = ref.child('${imagePciker.path.split('/')}');
      await ref2.putFile(File(imagePciker.path));
      final ListResult listData = await ref.listAll();
      final data =await ref2.getDownloadURL();
      print('Im HERE!=Line 95');
      Future.forEach(listData.items, (Reference element) async {
        await element.getDownloadURL().then((value) => listUrls.add(value));
        print('line 101');
        print(listUrls.length);
      });

      print('Line 104');
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('test').add({
        'titleDownloadUrl': data,
        'ListOfDownloadUrl': listUrls,
      });
      print('Line 108');
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
   /*    setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      }); */
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

The print statements are to debug. This whole function returns and no errors are thrown.
However in the firebase collection 'test' the URLs are not stored correctly.

**On the first/fresh run after restart of the app.**
the array of ListOfDownloadUrl is empty

**On a hot restart(with the no images saved in firebase storage)**
the array of ListOfDownloadUrl has one URL

then on multiple restarts, the amount of URLs saved becomes huge(ie. 4 images uploaded-10 URLs saved).

Please comment if I need to add anything else;
Thanks for any Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Following the thinking of @LeadDreamer

The forEach isn't ASYNCHRONOUS, the problem with his answer is that flutter does not have

> Promise.all()

What it does have if Future.wait(), which acts(in my case) the same way.

```
Future<void> saveImages() async {
    int index = images.length;
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    try {
      final refMain = FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child('images${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid}');
      AssetEntity eleId =
          new AssetEntity(id: '', typeInt: 5, width: 5, height: 5);

      await Future.wait(images.map((element) async { <-- here instead of the for each
        setState(() {
          eleId = element;
        });
        final file = await element.file;
        final refPut = refMain.child('suportImage$_counter/$element$index');
        await refPut.putFile(
          File(file!.path),
        );
      }));

      final ref2 =
          refMain.child('headingImage$_counter/${imagePciker.path.split('/')}');
      await ref2.putFile(File(imagePciker.path));
      final ListResult listData =
          await refMain.child('suportImage$_counter').listAll();
      final data = await ref2.getDownloadURL();
      await Future.wait(listData.items.map((e) async { <-- here instead of for each
        await e.getDownloadURL().then((value) => listUrls.add(value));
      }));
```

Answer (score 3):

`.forEach()` is NOT ASYNCHRONOUS - it WILL NOT wait.  Use `await Promise.all(images.map())` (thus creating an array of promises, which must all resolve).

Comment: What is a promise. I cannot find anything relating to a promise in flutter, Only promise to future